# Multiple Cartan sub-algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

> How is it that for a Semi-simple Lie Algebra there is not one Cartan Sub-Algebra?

I assume since there are multiple CSA's of a SS Lie algebra that must mean some of the ss elements of the Lie algebra get caught in other weight/root spaces corresponding to non-zero weights/roots? If not what happens to the SS elements not in the Cartan?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All Cartan subalgebras of a given s.s. Lie algebra are conjugate under Lie algebra automorphism of the the large algebra anyway, so there *is* essentially only one choice. (At least this is true over fields of characteristic $0$, I don't know what how this plays out in prime characteristic.)

Comment: But what technically makes one Cartan different from the other?

Comment: They are literally distinct subalgebras---one will contain elements that the other does not and vice versa. But since they are all conjugate, the representation-theoretic features one derives from a CSA (e.g. the root space decomposition) are all invariants of a SS Lie algebra up to conjugacy.

Comment: Ok, so the root space decomp is the same no matter what CSA you choose? In addition if the CSA of a SS Lie algebra contains only semisimple elements, but not all of its SS elements, what happens to the other SS elements not in the chosen CSA? Are they just in the other root spaces? Thank you for your help

Comment: Literally the root space decomposition is into different subspaces, but again, everything is the same up to conjugacy, and thus up to isomorphism; so once you understand everything that's going on with one choice of CSA you understand what's going on with every CSA. That's why in practice no one worries much about the particular choice, and why you should just choose one convenient for your purposes, e.g., one that sits nicely inside of the representation of the SS Lie algebra you're working with.

Comment: In the situation you describe, the other SS elements simply aren't in the new CSA. In general, I think they won't be contained in another root space but will be linear combinations of elements in other root spaces. It might be instructive to work out explicit root space decompositions for two choices of CSA for, say, $\mathfrak{sl}(3, \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. Makes sense. That's good advice to try to work it out for $\mathfrak {sl}_3$. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I find working out examples is often helpful when learning new mathematics in general, but I've found this especially true for studying semisimple Lie groups and algebras---this topic is especially nice because all of the examples are essentially classified.